# changing jQuery mobile slider value

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to reset or change the value of a jQuery slider based on the clicking of a button but to no luck. What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/yXXVr/

```
<input class="ui-hidden-accessible" type="range" name="slider1" id="slider1" value="50" min="0" max="100" animate="true" />
<br/>
<br>
<input class="ui-hidden-accessible" type="range" name="slider2" id="slider2" value="50" min="0" max="100" animate="true" />
<br/>
<input type="button" data-theme="a" id="go-back" value="Done"></input>

$('#go-back').click(function () {
    $("#slider1").val(50).refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There were a few things wrong with what you had in your jsFiddle. There were a few syntax errors, as well as an extra click handler defined for the Done button.

```
<input class="ui-hidden-accessible" data-track-theme="b" data-theme="a" type="range" name="slider1" id="slider1" value="50" min="0" max="100" animate="true" />
<br/>
<br>
<input class="ui-hidden-accessible" data-track-theme="b" data-theme="a" type="range" name="slider2" id="slider2" value="50" min="0" max="100" animate="true" />
<br/>
<input type="button" data-theme="a" id="go-back" value="Done" ></input>
```

Then in the JS, you were missing a closing parenthesis & semicolon at the very end, as well as calling `.refresh()` instead of `.slider("refresh")`

```
$('#go-back').click(function () {
    debugger;
    $("#slider1").val(50).slider("refresh");
});
```

Check out this updated fiddle for a working sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/yXXVr/2/

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

First, remove `onclick` from demo:

```
<input type="button" data-theme="a" id="go-back" value="Done" onclick="minbutton_clicked()"></input>
```

to

```
<input type="button" data-theme="a" id="go-back" value="Done"></input>
```

Second, you did not close the `.click()` function:

```
$('#go-back').click(function () {
    $("#slider1").val(50).refresh();
} 
 ^----- need )
```

Third, `.refresh()` does not exist. You need to use [`refresh method`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/#method-refresh):

```
$('#go-back').click(function () {
    $("#slider1").val(50).slider("refresh");
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/yXXVr/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type='range' min='0' max='100' value='0' id='slider' />
<input type='button' value='change value' id="changeval" />

    $("#changeval").click(function () {
    $("#page").page();
    $("#slider").val(30).slider('refresh');

})
```

#page refers to the page where #slider exists.