# jQuery mobile sliders reset on button click

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I am trying to have my jQuery mobile sliders reset when a button is pressed.

Here is the code for the form:

```
<div class="sliders">
        <input class="ui-hidden-accessible" data-track-theme="b" data-theme="a" type="range" name="slider1" id="slider1" value="50" min="0" max="100" animate="true"/><br/>
        <input class="ui-hidden-accessible" data-track-theme="b" data-theme="a" type="range" name="slider2" id="slider2" value="50" min="0" max="100" animate="true"/><br/> 
        <button data-theme="a" id="go-back">Done Rating</button>
</div>
```

And here is the JS (it is in the context of a D3 vizualization):

```
$('#go-back').click(function () {
    //$('#slider1').val(50).slider("refresh");
     $('.rate').slideUp();
    $('.frame').hide();                                
    _this.transition()
        .attr('r', _this.attr('data-r'))
        .duration(1000);

});
```

As above, it works fine and the transitions execute when the button is pressed. If I uncomment the line to reset the slider, the button does nothing when I press on it.

I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slider`.

I know this is the correct command to reset the slider, because I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627755/changing-jquery-mobile-slider-value).

EDIT: here's the list of JS imports:

```
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/csrf-ajax.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/8MDAE/ what version of jQuery and jQuery mobile are you using? Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: did you forget jquery ui?

Comment: Your code works well, what's the problem?

Comment: @Edward It's hard for me to provide a fiddle. Please see my list of imports above. You're right it's probably got to do with my versioning.

Comment: @Four_lo Please see my list of imports above.

Comment: Works fine with your include http://jsfiddle.net/8MDAE/1/, I miss only csrf-ajax. It seems a multiple jQuery core include issue; you have only a version of jQuery included right?